# findAssocs (tm) returns not computing correct correlation , returns 1 for all the words compared

Tags: r, tm

I need help figuring out what I am doing wrong. I have created the corpus from 2 text files and the DocumentTermMatrix is created but the correlations are returning the value 1 as if the data was checking correlation between a word and its own or if all the words belonged to the same vector. At one moment though it was a delimiter issue when importing into the corpus however I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
setwd("C:/Users/kangom/Documents")
options(stringAsFactors = FALSE)
library(tm)
docs <- Corpus(DirSource("cmtxtmining"))
summary(docs)
```

Summary results:

```
#A corpus with 2 text documents

#The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
#Available tags are:
#  create_date creator 
#Available variables in the data frame are:
#  MetaID
```

Then I did:

```
docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)
inspect(dtms[1:2, 1:50])
```

Inspect result:

```
#A document-term matrix (2 documents, 50 terms)

#Non-/sparse entries: 100/0
#Sparsity           : 0%
#Maximal term length: 20 
#Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

#                Terms
#Docs             aaron abilities ability able accelerate accept accepting
#  cmstrenght.txt     2         4     119   16          1      4         1
#  cmweakness.txt     1         2      17   29         13      2         2
#                Terms
#Docs             accepts accident accidents accomplish accomplishments
#  cmstrenght.txt      10      113        17          3               2
#  cmweakness.txt       2      105        37          2               2
#                Terms
#Docs             accordingly account accountabilities accountability
#  cmstrenght.txt           1       1                2             54
#  cmweakness.txt           1       2                2            141
```

The list goes on...

```
findAssocs(dtms, "account", corlimit=0.6) #(similar result with findAssocs(dtm, "account", corlimit=0.6))

#                             account
#able                               1
#accelerate                         1
#accepting                          1
#accidents                          1
#accountability                     1
#accountable                        1
#accountably                        1
#achieve                            1
#acquisition                        1
#across                             1
#acting                             1
#action                             1
#active                             1
#activities                         1
#adapting                           1
#address                            1
#addressing                         1
#adjust                             1
#aesb                               1
#affect                             1
#aggressive                         1
#aggressively                       1
#aggressiveness                     1
#aim                                1
#alex                               1
#align                              1
#aligned                            1
#alignment                          1
#alive                              1
#allow                              1
#...
#zero                               1
```

Comment: I am not sure of this, but with only two documents, and 50 words total, perhaps both words you have tried are in both documents, therefore the association is 100%, ie. 1.

Comment: Thanks. 
I ended up figuring out the issue. The corpus was being created without seperating the line it was like a long sentence being analyzes.
I used the package gsubfn to read the line when th a tab separator and load it into a dataframe. Then using DataframeSource dor creating the corpus. All good now.

Comment: Typo: gsubfn helped read the lines in the text with a tab separator